# Is it possible to highlight a NSString or draw some color to a string

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

i am having this code to get the text between "." for example i am having lots of text like .1 this is first.2 this is second.3 this is fourth etc etc.when i tap the first ext it displays the first text in log .the code is

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:maintextview   selector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSRange selectedRange = [textView selectedRange];
    NSString *backString = [maintextview.text substringToIndex:selectedRange.location];
    NSRange backRange = [backString rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    NSRange backRangee = [backString rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    int  myRangeLenght = backRangee.location - backRange.location;
    NSRange myStringRange = NSMakeRange (backRange.location, myRangeLenght);
    NSString *forwardString  = [maintextview.text substringFromIndex:backRange.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[forwardString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:1]);

}
```

forwadString contains the tapped text,i just want to highlight this string or draw a color above this text using core graphics or something like that.is out possible?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to 'colour' an `NSString`, a string is just a representation of characters, it holds no font, colour or style properties. Instead you need to colour the UI element that draws the text to the screen.

If forwardString is in a `UILabel` or `UITextView` you can colour the text inside these by setting the `textColor` property. For example if you had a `UILabel` called `lbl` you could set the colour by using:

```
lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: is it posable to set a condition i the textview.text is forwrdstring then text.textcolor = [uicolor yellow color];?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to set the textView's delegate, and  override a method (such as textDidChange). This way, whenever text is changed in the textview, this method will fire. Put your logic for setting the colour in there

Answer (score 2):

Much to my and many other's disappointment, Apple chose not to implement [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) until iOS 3.2, and even then, all standard UI elements are incapable of rendering them!

Luckily, the few, the proud, and the brave have answered the call and [DTCoreText](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nsattributedstring-additions-for-html) was born.

As for an actual selection, because UITextView conforms to UITextInput as of iOS 3.2, you can use and set the `selectedTextRange`.

Comment: ,how can we select the forwardstring ,like the default copy paste selection?

Comment: @CodaFi I'm very interested in selectable NSAttributedStrings for my project so I can stop using the nasty slow UIWebView...I can't find a portion of that project that inherits from UITextView, though, so does DTCoreText support selections and UIMenu items?